# How to set network interface to use in WCF service?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I dont have much knowledge on WCF. I have a WPF tablet application using WCF service to communicate with another instance of WPF application on other tablet.

WPF application places a pull request from other tablet's database via WCF service. This WCF service on the tablet fetches the data from database and sends it over TCP back to the requesting application. Same happens vice versa. Hence the synchronization is achieved. It happens over WiFi interface.

```
private const string WCFSERVICE_URL = "net.tcp://{0}:{1}/SynchronizeService"
```

Some code where we configure the client:

```
private DrillSynchronizeClient CreateConfigureClient(DrillNetInfo Drill)
    {
        DrillSynchronizeClient synchClient = new DrillSynchronizeClient();

        string endpointUrl = String.Format(WCFSERVICE_URL, Drill.Ip, wcfServiceNetworkPort);
        EndpointAddress serviceAddress = new EndpointAddress(endpointUrl);

        NetTcpBinding netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
        netTcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
        netTcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;

        netTcpBinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        netTcpBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        netTcpBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        netTcpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);

        netTcpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;
        netTcpBinding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
        netTcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;

        synchClient.Endpoint.Address = serviceAddress;
        synchClient.Endpoint.Binding = netTcpBinding;

        return synchClient;
    }
```

This works fine when there is not internet connection available on these tablets.

When tablets are connected to internet via internet USB dongle, this synchronization stops working. Is the WCF trying to use the internet adapter(dongle) to resolve the WCF service IP address endpoint ?? Not sure, how to bind the WCF service to use only WLAN interface for communication.

Also please let me know where to specify/bind the source interface IP address to use when calling WCF request.

Thanks.